# c# POST request with HttpWebRequest gets converted to GET request on web service (php)

Tags: c#, php, json, post, httpwebrequest

I am using this method to post json data to a self made web request in php:

```
private string Post(string jsonContent)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost");

        var encoding = new UTF8Encoding();
        var byteArray = encoding.GetBytes(jsonContent);

        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        request.ContentType = @"application/json";
        request.Method = "POST";

        try
        {
            using (var dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            }
            using (StreamReader responseStream = new StreamReader(((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()).GetResponseStream()))
            {
                return responseStream.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch(WebException ex)
        {
            Log(ex);
            return string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

While this is the php script **index.php**

```
<?php
    //Make sure that it is a POST request.
    if(strcasecmp($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'], 'POST') != 0)
    {
        var_dump($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']);
        throw new Exception('Request method must be POST!');
    }

    //Make sure that the content type of the POST request has been set to application/json
    $contentType = isset($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) ? trim($_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"]) : '';
    if(strcasecmp($contentType, 'application/json') != 0)
    {
        var_dump($contentType);
        throw new Exception('Content type must be: application/json');
    }

    //Receive the RAW post data.
    $content = trim(file_get_contents("php://input"));

    //Attempt to decode the incoming RAW post data from JSON.
    $decoded = json_decode($content, true);

    //If json_decode failed, the JSON is invalid.
    if(!is_array($decoded)){
        throw new Exception('Received content contained invalid JSON!');
    }

    //Process the JSON.
    var_dump($decoded);

?>
```

When i now call the c# method like this `var response = Post("{\"foo\":\"bar\"}");` it results in the error **'Request method must be POST!'**. Because it actually is GET.

I am using WTServer to use nginx on Windows 10. Nginx 1.11.4, PHP 7.0.11 and this is the response:

```
<pre class='xdebug-var-dump' dir='ltr'>
    <small>C:\WTServer\WWW\index.php:6:</small><small>string</small> <font color='#cc0000'>'GET'</font> <i>(length=3)</i>
</pre><br />
<font size='1'>
    <table class='xdebug-error xe-uncaught-exception' dir='ltr' border='1' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='1'>
        <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Request method must be POST! in C:\WTServer\WWW\index.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
        <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#f57900' colspan="5"><span style='background-color: #cc0000; color: #fce94f; font-size: x-large;'>( ! )</span> Exception: Request method must be POST! in C:\WTServer\WWW\index.php on line <i>7</i></th></tr>
        <tr><th align='left' bgcolor='#e9b96e' colspan='5'>Call Stack</th></tr>
        <tr><th align='center' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>#</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Time</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Memory</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Function</th><th align='left' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>Location</th></tr>
        <tr><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>1</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='center'>0.2190</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec' align='right'>360056</td><td bgcolor='#eeeeec'>{main}(  )</td><td title='C:\WTServer\WWW\index.php' bgcolor='#eeeeec'>...\index.php<b>:</b>0</td></tr>
    </table>
</font>
```

Comment: Ok. Now if i change `"http://localhost"` to `"http://localhost/index.php"` it works. So this means some misconfiguration in php or nginx, right? Can someone give a newbie a hint, please?

Comment: I'm getting a seimilar issue with WordPress right now and I'd love to know if you ever figured out what was going on here Luke

Comment: Unfortunately no. I did not get a solution to this.

Comment: It's so strange I have a very similar issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59687853/post-request-changed-to-get-request-when-making-a-request-from-c-sharp-to-wordpr